# how to add signle qute to awk print / SQL insert from bash script AWK print single quote SQL insert from bash script

Tags: sql, bash, awk, printing, insert

I need to prepare bash script witch will be creating sql inserts from output file with accounts list.
Script work properly but i dont know how to create single quote

How insert should looks like: - expected output :

```
INSERT into LIST_VALUES 
(DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP) 
values ('aaa', 'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', TO_DATE('05/09/2018 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'CS' , 'DSS' ,  '111111', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII'));
```

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk  ' NR == 1,NR == 8  { print  "INSERT into LIST_VALUES (DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECTIVE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP) values ('aaa', 'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', 'TO_DATE','"05/09/2018"', '"00:00:00"','"MM/DD/YYYY"', '"HH24:MI:SS"' , 'CS' , 'DSS'   , $0  , 'TO_CHAR', '"SYSDATE (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII)"' "  } ' /home/maciej/hs/lista2
```

output looks ok but removes all single quotes in 'VALUES' I tried use \ but it doesn't work. Please help me prepare script which will have all needed single quotes

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please post sample of expected output too in your too, to make it more clear; thank you.

Comment: INSERT into LIST_VALUES 
(DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP) 
values ('aaa', 'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', TO_DATE('05/09/2018 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'CS' , 'DSS' ,  '111111', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII'));

Comment: @MaciejPelczar don't add information in comments - [edit] your question to provide all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep things simple, use echo and insert double quotes around the SQL statement. For example,

```
echo "INSERT into LIST_VALUES (DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP) values ('aaa', 'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', TO_DATE('05/09/2018 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'CS' , 'DSS' ,  '111111', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII'));"
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to make script witch takes output file txt to awk and create for example 10000 sql inserts with changing only accounts number:

but I dont know how to add single quote to resault.

How to make output with : ' - single quote. Bash delete it by itself.

My script:

#!/bin/bash
awk  ' NR == 1,NR == 8  { print  "INSERT into LIST_VALUES (DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECTIVE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP) values ('aaa', 'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', 'TO_DATE',**'"05/09/2018"', '"00:00:00"','"MM/DD/YYYY"', '"HH24:MI:SS"'** , 'CS' , 'DSS'   , $0  , 'TO_CHAR', '"SYSDATE (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII)"' "  } ' /home/maciej/hs/lista2

output without single quotes:

INSERT into LIST_VALUES
(DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP)
values (aaa, XXX, OK, NO, **TO_DATE(05/09/2018 00:00:00,MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS**) , CS , DS ,  111111, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII));

expected output:

INSERT into LIST_VALUES
(DEPA, OFFA, STATUS, CHANGE_STATUS, EFFECE_DATE, ACTION, LIST, VALUE, TIME_STAMP)
values ('aaa', **'XXX', 'OK', 'NO', TO_DATE('05/09/2018 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'**) , 'CS' , 'DSS' ,  '111111', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MII'));

how to make script to not delete single quote in output ?

Comment: Don't add information relevant to your question in an answer, just click the "edit" button under your question and update it.